# Get the rule from an already resampled series

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I'm writing a function that must receive a resample series as an argument. I need to know what's was the resample rule.

For example let s a series:

```
0      2011-01-01 00:00:00
1      2011-01-01 00:30:00
2      2011-01-01 01:00:00
3      2011-01-01 01:30:00
4      2011-01-01 02:00:00
```

I need a method that returns me '6H' when entering s.

Comment: Why should it return '6H' ??? Why not "00:30:00" (the step between each sample) or "02:00:00" (the difference between the last and first sample) ? Or any other parameter ? You have to give us more details about the process you want to perform...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.freq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.freq.html) but is necessary frequency is specified, not `None`:

```
print (s.dt.freq)
30T
```

If there is `DatetimeIndex` then use [`DatetimeIndex.freq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.freq.html) or 
[`DatetimeIndex.freqstr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.freqstr.html):

```
print (s.index.freq)
print (s.index.freqstr)
```